# Prove that $T-\lambda I$ has minimal polynomial $q(z)=p(z+\lambda)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, minimal-polynomials

I am learning Linear Algebra Done Right. Here is a question from 5B.

Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional, $T\in L(V)$, and $p$ is the minimal polynomial of T. Suppose $\lambda\in F$. Show that the minimal polynomial of $T-\lambda I$ is defined by $q(z)=p(z+\lambda)$.

Up to this point, I can only write like the following:

By the definition of minimal polynomial, $p(T)=0$, then $q(T-\lambda I)=p(T)=0$, but this only shows that $q$ is a multiple of the minimal polynomial of $T-\lambda I$. How can I show this is the minimal polynomial?

Comment: Simply note that $T = (T - \lambda I) + \lambda I$, and reapply your argument.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Do the same trick for $T_0 = T - \lambda I$ and $\lambda_0 = -\lambda$ and consider degrees. More concretely, if $p_0$ is minimal polynomial of $T_0$ different from $q$, what's the relation between $q_0$ and $p$ and what does it tell you about minimality of $p$?